# Audit logging CosmosDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-log-analytics

Wanting to validate my ARM template was deployed ok and to get an understanding of the telemetry options...

Under what circumstances do the following get logged to Log Analytics?

- DataPlaneRequests
- MongoRequests
- QueryRuntimeStatistics
- Metrics

From what I can tell arduously in the last few days connecting in different ways.

DataPlaneRequests are logged for:

- SQL API calls
- Table API calls **even when** the account was setup for SQL API
- Graph API calls against an account setup for Graph API
- Table API calls against an account setup for Table API

MongoRequests are logged for:

- Mongo requests **even when** the account was setup for SQL API

However I haven't been able to see anything for QueryRuntimeStastics (even when turning on PopulateQueryMetrics) nor have I seen any AzureMetrics appear?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Alex for spending time and trying out different options of logging for Azure Cosmos DB.

There are primarily two types of monitoring paths for Azure Cosmos DB.

1. Metrics: These are low latency (<5 min) and aggregated metrics which are exposed on Azure Monitor API for consumption. THese metrics are primarily used for diagnosis of the app for any live site issues.
2. Logs: These are raw request logs coming at 2hours+ latency and are used for customer for primarily audit scenarios to understand who accessed the data.

Depending on your need you can choose either of the approaches.

DataPlaneRequests by default shows all the requests across all the API's and Mongo Requests only show Mongo specific calls. Please note Mongo requests would also be seen in Data Plane requests.

Metrics would not be see in Log Analytics due to a knowwn which our partner team is fixing.

Let me know if you have any further questions here.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer, may I ask what causes QueryRuntimeStatistics to be logged? Also Is there a uservoice ticket or similar tracking the issue with the metrics being logged into Log Analytics?

Comment: Also may I ask will the private preview Casandra API be logging to DataPlaneRequests as well?

Comment: Thanks, @AlexKeySmith for asking this question. Did you find the answer when QueryRuntimeStastics logged and what exact information it provides?

Comment: Hi, no I didn't, but didn't end up looking any further as I got as far as I needed. I suspect turning on PopulateQueryMetrics perhaps makes data get sent to log analytics as well? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query-metrics